# Checking digits with decimal separator defined

Tags: c#, linq

I have a function as below (I am not to much familiar with linq)

```
    public static bool IsNumber(string s, char dec_sep)
    {
        return s.Length > 0 && s.All(c => Char.IsDigit(c));
    }
```

If the number contains a decimal separator I get false as a fact.
I want to check if my defined decimal separator is in the number
Is it possible modify this function for this purpose ?
Or should I write another function ?

For being more clear

If in the string there ise decimal separator such as 72.5 it returns false (my defined separator is "." ). It already returns true if the string is 72 or 725.
I want this function returns TRUE even with a decimal separator.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Are you trying to parse a string representing a decimal number?

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more I don't get it what you want?

Comment: What if you have two decimal separators? Why not use the already built in `float.TryParse`?

Comment: And what about thousands separators? In my language (and many others), `1,234.56` is a perfectly valid number.... What about cultural differences? What if someone wants to use Arabic or Thai numerals? For instance - `สามสิบเอ็ด` means 31 in Thai (at least, according to [this website](http://www.thai-language.com/ref/numbers)) and `٧٧٥٤٢` is 77,542...

Comment: @ZoharPeled The comma I use for special purpose in my program so I limited to DOT.  So I don't use culturalinfo for the selection of decmal separator.

Comment: @AkshayKatoch I added and exemple for the clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise against writing your own "IsNumber" function.

The framework already has `TryParse` of all built in value types - so I suggest using either `float.TryParse`, `double.TryParse` or `decimal.TryParse` depending on the size and precision of number you're expecting (23, 64 or 128 bit).

Writing your own "IsNumber" function is bound to have some difficulties, especially if you're going to attempt to parse user input (or any input you can't control, for that matter) - because like many other "simple" things, numbers are nothing but simple.

First, Numbers can have a thousands separator - in English, 1,234.56 is a valid number.
Second, string representations of numbers are culture dependent - 1,234.56 is **invalid** in some cultures - where the decimal separator is a comma and the thousands separator is a dot - so you would actually write it like this: 1.234,56
Note that these are two different ways to write the same number -
one thousand, two hundred thirty-four and fifty-six hundredths.
Even worst, you can write the same number in different numerals altogether - Thai, Arabic, Chinese or Hebrew - all of these languages (and probably many more languages) have their own symbols for numbers - and I'm not sure that `IsDigit` covers them all (though it's probably culture dependent also).

---

Having said all that, your current function will throw a `NullReferenceException` if the string is null - the very least you should do is either throw an `ArgumentNullException` or simply return false if the string is null.
Further more, there are going to be valid use-case where you want to know if a char exists exactly zero or once in a string - one way to do it is by subtracting `IndexOf` from `LastIndexOf` and check that the result of this subtruction is `0`.
To combine that with your current method, you also want to change the condition in the `All` method to allow the char to either be a digit or your designated decimal separator.

If you really have to write your own method, here's how I would start it:

```
public static bool IsNumber(string s, char dec_sep)
{
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)
        && s.LastIndexOf(dec_sep) - s.IndexOf(dec_sep) == 0 
        && s.All(c => Char.IsDigit(c) || c == dec_sep);
}
```

The first condition will return false if the string is null or empty,
the second one will return false only if the string contains `dec_sep` more than once,
and the third will return false only if the string contains any char that is neither a digit nor `dec_sep`.

Comment: Thanks that's what I need. I wrote another function but I like this trick of linq

Comment: There's no trick of linq here. The only linq part in this is `s.All`...

Answer (score 1):

If you are a fan of regex you can also try `"^\\d+\\.??(\\d*)?$"`